# Using pcaCoda from the package "robCompositions" with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I would like to plot the results of the robust PCA (pcaCoDa) from the robCompositions package using ggplot2.

Previously, it worked with ggbiplot (https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot) however, I can no longer get it to work with my current R version (3.6.0).

Is there a way to do a biplot with the pcaCoda results with ggplot2 using CRAN packages?
Here is a working example without using ggplot:

```
library(robCompositions)
df <- arcticLake
a <- pcaCoDa(df)
biplot(a)
```

And another example without using the robust PCA, but using the autoplot function:

```
library(ggplot2)    
autoplot(princomp(df))
```

However, I would like to use the robust PCA with ggplot/autoplot. When I try to plot it, i get the following error:

```
autoplot(a)
```

> Error: Objects of type pcaCoDa not supported by autoplot.

I also tried the following and also get an error:

```
autoplot(a$princompOutputClr)
```

> Error in scale.default(data, center = FALSE, scale = 1/scale) :
>   length of 'scale' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons that I ignore `pcaCoda` returns one value less for `scale` and `center` compared to the output of other pca methods such as `prcomp` or `princomp`.  I think that's the reason why `autoplot` does not want to plot this object.

Alternatively, if you want to apply the `robust` algortithm, you can use the package `pcaMethods` available on `bioconductor`, here i provided an example using the `iris` dataset that you can found on the documentation of `pcaMethods` (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/pcaMethods.html):

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("pcaMethods")

library(pcaMethods)
library(ggplot2)

robust = pca(iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)], method = "robustPca", scale = "uv", center = TRUE)
iris = merge(iris, scores(robust), by =0)

ggplot(iris, aes( x= PC1, y = PC2, colour = Species))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse()
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to get ?